Running Excel Interop in AWS Workspace via Task Scheduler: Seeking Advice
I have a process that updates an Excel file using EPPlus, and this part works fine when scheduled to run at a specific hour using Task Scheduler.
However, now I need to update external data connections, pivot tables, etc., and I’m doing this using Excel Interop. Here's where the problem starts: I can only successfully run this part when the process runs interactively (i.e., when the user is logged in).
When I run it via Task Scheduler with the setting "Run only when user is logged on," it works, but if I close the connection, or if the AWS Workspace restarts, the task fails to start with the error "Launch condition not met, user not logged-on." I've tried using PsExec, which almost solved the issue, but it introduced new problems.
My question is: is there a way to schedule a task on Windows that involves running an interactive process like Excel Interop? I’m open to developing a Windows Service, but I suspect I’ll run into similar problems.
Does anyone have advice on the best approach to ensure Excel Interop can run successfully via Task Scheduler or another method?
What i have tried and the results:

Tried task scheduler starting just the .exe and parameters - got an error saying it cannot access the file (same process does not have this error when running interactively)
Tried "Run only when user is logged on" - It seems the user session does not persist and the task does not trigger
Tried running with psexec: "psexec -i" - did not work (it seems is running in session 0) and have the same problem as running with only exe and prameters
Tried running with psexec: "psexec -i 1" - it runs on session 1 but console is bugged (does not show anything and even the windows buttons are missing - buttons to close and minimize console)
Changed the task to call a .bat instead but got the same problems


For anyone who has this issue in the future: it is possible to run Interop with a non-interactive task. I was able to make it work tweaking CSOM settings. Here are the steps:

Open dcomcnfg
Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.
Type dcomcnfg and press Enter. This will open the Component Services window.
Navigate to Microsoft Excel Application
In the Component Services window, expand the following:
Component Services → Computers → My Computer → DCOM Config.
Scroll down the list until you find Microsoft Excel Application.
The entries are listed alphabetically, so it will be towards the middle.
Configure DCOM Properties for Excel
Right-click on Microsoft Excel Application and choose Properties.

A new window will open. Now follow the steps below to configure permissions:
General Tab:
Ensure that Authentication Level is set to Default.
Security Tab:
Under Launch and Activation Permissions, click Customize and then Edit.
Add the user account that runs the Task Scheduler job and grant it the following permissions:
Local Launch: Allow
Remote Launch: (only if you plan to run Excel from another machine)
Local Activation: Allow
Remote Activation: (only if running from another machine)
Under Access Permissions, click Customize and then Edit.
Add the user or service account running the task and give it access permissions as needed.
Identity Tab:
Here, choose how you want Excel to run. You have three options:
The interactive user: This runs Excel only when a user is logged in.
The launching user: This runs Excel using the user who launches the task.
This user: You can specify a specific user account (provide username and password) to run Excel.
If you want Excel to run as a background task, choose This user and provide the credentials of a user that has the necessary permissions.
IMPORTANT: This step is crucial. Although it is true that will work if you set up as “This user”, you will have problems with excel in interactive mode. What i did instead is to select “The interactive user” and both interactive and non-interactive tasks are working now.

Restart the DCOM Service
Once you've configured DCOM for Excel, you might need to restart the DCOM service. You can do this by restarting the machine or using the following steps:

Open Services (press Win + R, type services.msc, and press Enter).
Find DCOM Server Process Launcher.
Right-click and select Restart.
